# how to go to previous line in php on windows command line

Tags: php, windows

I have a the following php code:

```
while(true){
    $r = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
    goToPreviousLine();
    echo $r;
}
```

How can i go to the previous line on the windows command line?

Comment: you can save to variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code helped me

```
echo "\033[1F";
```